# Database Error 1364 in Solspace Calendar

Tags: solspace-calendar

We recently had a server failure that resulted in having to rebuild the server services. Ended up going from mySQL 5.1 to 5.6.23. Since that issue occurred, one of our clients is reporting that Calendar gives him this error when trying to create new events:

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1364

Field 'last_date' doesn't have a default value

Client reports that entry gets made, just doesn't have an date info in the Calendar field.

It's EE 2.8.1 and Calendar 1.8.9.

Comment: Have you manually checked that table column to make sure that it does have a default?

Comment: Nope. But I'm headed that way... I've also received some feedback from Solspace. I think I'll have this fixed in a few and will post my actions for future me or whoever else may need it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue shown here was resolved by adding a default value (0) into the exp_calendar_events table, 'last_date' field. Not sure how it got gone, perhaps it was a result of the mysql version change or maybe the missing value wasn't an issue until the version change, but adding the default value resolved the issue for me.

Comment: "_...doesn't have a default value_" errors can happen when **strict mode** is enabled in MySQL. If you turn this off the error usually would go away. The other approach is to indeed add a default value yourself in the table if you have strict more kept enabled.

Comment: Disabling strict mode has helped me in this case. But it's only a temporary Situation since I'm on a shared hosting. The server guys won't keep the strict mode disabled for a long time.

Comment: The error message sais that it's on Line Number: 903, Filename: third_party/calendar/data.calendar.php. Would it be possible to make this somehow work with stict mode enable? Calendar 1.8.14.