# MySQL ERROR: Error Number: 1364 Description: Field 'whatever' doesn't have a default value

Tags: error, mysql, default

Firstable, I´m  designer, hence my ignorance.
It´s been awhile since I didn´t updated a site. The client asked me to make a new member in EE. I´ve been able always to do that on the spot, but this time I always get the SQL error of the email subject (1364). After some researching, I tried to publish some entry and I got the same SQL error.

Then i found this post here
[Database Error 1364 in Solspace Calendar](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/32884/database-error-1364-in-solspace-calendar)

The point is that i´m not sure if I have to adding a default value (0) to all the tables or there is a way to do that for the whole site.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I had this error on a site recently and I fixed it by removing strict mode from MySQL.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37964325/how-to-find-and-disable-mysql-strict-mode

^ That has some information on the matter. I'm not sure what your current setup is but the update is fairly standard. Find the cnf file, remove "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES" from the string and save, then restart MySQL.

Comment: I tried to turn strict mode off in phpmyadmin, but I get the Error Number: 1227. Description: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation. And I can´t see users or privileges in the phpmyadmin tabs, so I guess I´ll have to contact with my hosting provider, right?

Thank you

Comment: Hmm, this does change things a bit. I've had issues with shared hosting locking me out of this too. Depending on what they say you may want to look back into the adding a default zero for the tables.

Comment: They said that I can't modify globally the server.I have to do that with php. The sent me this example

Comment: <?php
 
$mysqli = mysqli_init();
if (!$mysqli) {
     die('mysqli_init failed');}
if (!$mysqli->options(MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND, "set session sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'")) {
     die('Setting MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND failed');}
if (!$mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 5)) {
     die('Setting MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT failed');}
if (!$mysqli->real_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db')) {
     die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
             . mysqli_connect_error());}
echo 'Success... ' . $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
$mysqli->close();
?>

Comment: But not quite sure how to implement this code. Some clue would be really appreciated. Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you run that code on a template with PHP enabled and then visit that page?

Comment: Hi Michael

If I try to create a new template, I get this error
MySQL ERROR:

Error Number: 1364

Description: Field 'template_notes' doesn't have a default value

Query: INSERT INTO `exp_templates` (`template_id`, `group_id`, `template_name`, `template_type`, `template_data`, `edit_date`, `site_id`) VALUES ('', '1', 'db', 'webpage', '', '1523966633', '1')

With a PHP page with the code and the database name, password, etc, 

I just get the following line
Success... qnq278.marcadores-discursivos.es via TCP/IP

Comment: I've had issues during the EE4 update process where I've had to edit the database to include default values or even new tables. Looking at a current site I have blanks in my template notes column. If you have something like PHPMyAdmin available to you this should help a lot.